# Bootstrap Collapse Expands Table Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to make a Bootstrap table that expands the rows when you click on the header and then closes again when you click the header again.

The code I have below does what I want it to do BUT the animation of the collapse and closing is way off.

It's a bit hard to explain but basically the rows seem to expand downwards around 5 times their original size (the text size is the same but the rows become huge), and the combined rows seem to take up half the screen and then the rows shrink back down to their original size and then the table displays correctly. This takes around half a second but it's very obvious and distracting. The width of the table remains the same throughout the animation..... only the height of the rows expands hugely!

Forgot to mention this happens in Internet Explorer 11. On Chrome there is no animation at all. It just snaps open and closed. I need it to work on Internet Explorer 11 thanks!

Any ideas please?

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="row" style="border:0px;">
            <div style="display:inline-block;padding:0px;">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#CodeNamesTable" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#854864;">
                            <th style="min-width:60px;">Code</th>
                            <th style="min-width:400px;">Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="collapse" id="CodeNamesTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>ABC</td>
                                <td>Notes For ABC Stock</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EER</td>
                                <td>Ordinary Enterprise Readouts</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>GRT</td>
                                <td>General Resource Target Funds</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>KLI</td>
                                <td>KLI Preference Indicators</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>WAW</td>
                                <td>Worldwide Administration Window</td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/9zum3vzf/1)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your jsfiddle has jquery so if you just want to use jquery try something like this => http://codepen.io/carlos27/pen/dpdyEb

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:403px;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:400px;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

JS

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

You can also use jqueryUI => https://jqueryui.com/accordion/